# Measuring the load time of individual GUI elements

Tags: android, ios, performance, user-interface, windows-phone-8.1

I am writing a program to measure the load time of every GUI element (like button, Text box etc.). Right now I am working on Windows Phone and I plan to expand it to Android and iOS (using swift probably, still undecided) and Java desktop.

I am using the click event of a button to generate a GUI element (a button in this case)

```
private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CleanUp(); // to Garbage collect

    watch.Start();
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Width = 110;
    btn.Height = 56;
    btn.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.White);
    btn.Content = "Button";
    btn.Click += btn_Click;
    gridMain.Children.Add(btn);
    watch.Stop(); 
}
```

I use a different button, with the following code in its event handler, to show the results

```
private void btnResults_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    long ticks = watch.ElapsedTicks;
    double ms = 1000.0 * (double)ticks / Stopwatch.Frequency;
    // show results in a message box
}
```

I also have a button to remove the generated button and garbage collect so that I can remove and recreate and take several readings

```
private void btnRemove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    gridMain.Children.RemoveAt(3); //the dynamically generated button is at 3
    watch.Reset();
}
```

The problem is that I am getting some what inconsistent results. 
Here are few of my results (excluding the first run):

```
0.6028 ms
0.7217 ms
0.9596 ms
1.3834 ms
0.5626 ms
1.3814 ms
0.7343 ms
```

I don't understand the reason. Is this significantly inconsistent? if yes, then is my method flawed? is there a better way to do this? Thanks

Comment: The uber question is "why are you doing this?" - what do you intend to achieve?

Comment: @peter Well, to measure the loading time of different GUI elements. The reason of doing so is more academic lets just say

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you're measuring constructing two objects (a `Button` and a `SolidColorBrush`), setting various properties, inserting a couple of things into vectors (the event handler and the children), etc. but I don't think the button is actually visible when you call `Stop` (there is probably a layout and render pass still to happen). So you're measuring some random things.

Off-hand (*and I'm not a XAML perf guru by any stretch of the imagination*) a variance of +/- 1ms **wall-clock time** for adding a `Button` to a `Grid` seems reasonable given the way you're measuring (eg, what else is your computer doing at the same time?). If you want to do perf analysis, use the performance analyzer tools.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but wouldn't using the visual studio's performance analysis tools incorporate more randomness than this?

Comment: It will tell you how much CPU time things actually take, rather than wall-clock time. But this is still not going to be very useful as data other than for curiosity.